# how safe are mysql login credentials in this

Tags: php, mysql

If the following codes are stored in www.examples.com/test.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
...
```

Are the password secured?
If not, what are the best practices to prevent unwanted access to the information?
Thanks!

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322766/php-basics-where-to-store-mysql-password-used-by-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's secure as long as nobody can access the text contents of test.php. A reasonable best practice would be to store the credentials somewhere that's not accessible by a visiting user, so that if for instance the contents of `example.com` are put in a folder `/some/path/to/www-data`, you could put the file somewhere else, like `/some/path/to/credentials.php`. That way, the web server can still load the file, but external users won't be able to access it.

In addition, while we're discussing MySQL/PHP best practices, please note that the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated, and for good reason. Instead, I suggest you use `mysqli_` (where the i stands for improved), or `PDO`. You can read more about it here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Even if the file was located at `/some/path/to/www-data/credentials.php` external users still wont be able to read anything. They can load the file in browser but unless you echo the credentials that wont help them

Comment: You're not wrong, but that's assuming the web server is always correctly set up. As I said, it's secure as long as nobody can access the text contents. But from past experiences with morons at previous workplaces, I find that one should never assume that will always be the case. All it takes is one clumsy developer serving the page as text content without processing it.

Comment: Yep that absolutely makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to place an .inc file in a non root directory and include this file as you can use a file path in both require and include

```
<?php

$host = 'example.org';
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';

$db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);

?>
```

if you must place this inside a root folder, some modification to the httpd.conf can apply some extra security (assuming you are using apache)

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Why `.inc` and not `.inc.php` ? That gives you double the protection

Comment: It depends. Because i mentioned that if the .inc is in a not root directory, it doesnt matter what the file extention is. If it is in a root directory, the rule will catch it.

Comment: Don't always rely solely on `.htaccess` files, one messed up setting for the virtual host can render them useless at times.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language, meaning that a client device will never actually see any PHP code.

What this means is that any passwords you have are perfectly safe, from client devices.

The file that contains the login information can still be accessed by a privileged user of the webserver.